# PeerJS peer not receiving data

Tags: javascript, peerjs

I intend to use PeerJs to create P2P connections (data and later video).
I checked the tutorial and used the following code.

In browserA (Chrome 38):

```
var local;
var remote;

function peerJsInit() {
    //listening host
    local = new Peer(
    {
        key: 'myPeerJSKey'
    });
    local.on('connection', function(conn) {
        alert('Connection is open');
        conn.on('data', function(data) {
            alert('Data: '+data);
        });
    });
}



function peerSend() {
    remote = new Peer(
    {
        key: 'myPeerJSKey',
        debug: true
    });
    var c = remote.connect('remoteId');
    c.on('open', function() {
        alert('connected');
        c.send(' peer');
    });

}
```

In browserB (Chrome 38):

```
var local;
var remote;

function peerJsInit() {
    //listening host
    local = new Peer({
        key: 'myPeerJSKey'
    });
    local.on('connection', function(conn) {
        alert('Connection is open');
        conn.on('data', function(data) {
            alert('Data: '+data);
        });
    });
}



function peerSend() {
    remote = new Peer({
        key: 'myPeerJSKey',
        debug: true
    });
    var c = remote.connect('remoteId');
    c.on('open', function() {
        alert('connected');
        c.send(' peer');
    });

}
```

The *Connection is open* message showed, but the *Data* and *connected* messages never.

Can you tell me what I should change?

Comment: I haven't looked at the code but have you tried firefox ? Because the peerJS code that I have doesn't work on my latest chrome but works on FF.

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla The code partially works, but the data handling code is not called (see the modified initial post).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that I forgot to add another callback. 
It is sooo good that JS compiles without a problem, even when callbacks are missing... piece of g*rbage...

So instead of this:

```
 local.on('connection', function(conn) {
        alert('Connection is open');
        conn.on('data', function(data) {
            alert('Data: '+data);
        });
    });
```

I have to use this:

```
 local.on('connection', function(conn) {
        alert('Connection is open');
        conn.on('open',function(){
        conn.on('data', function(data) {
            alert('Data: '+data);
        });
       });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, i was struggling with this until i found your answer.

Comment: @user4479807 Glad it could help :)